# Are judges still making decisions in the Crown Court?

Tags: england-and-wales, jury, judging

If a judge's main duty mainly revolves on decision-making, what about Crown Court judges?

Since juries are deployed in a small percentage of cases at the crown court and they are the ones who make the decision as to whether or not the defendant is guilty or not guilty, can we still say that the crown court judge is still making decision? I'm confused.

Answer (score 2):

Judges make all sorts of decisions.  Some are administrative, such as setting the trial timetable, but most are significant and often in response to applications made to the court by counsel - They decide, for example:

- whether evidence is admissible
- whether there is [no case to answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_case_to_answer)
- To accept a majority verdict
- The sentence for a guilty verdict
- Whether to grant leave for appeal

Comment: And, of course, to determine if there is a right to a jury trial at all in a particular kind of matter.